# AdMob mediation doesn't generate impressions

Tags: android, admob, inmobi, mobile-ad-mediation

I was using AdMob to display their Ads in my android app and it was working great. I decided to try ad mediation with AdMob. I followed their guidelines, registered an account in InMobi and set up everything that I was supposed to (I guess). But now there is no difference in displaying ads. I mean I still get ads from google, and only from google (just like earlier). InMobi and AdMob show that I didn't generate any impressions and I have no idea what could have gone wrong.

For the record I changed my "ads:adUnitId" in layout, app was in market for more than 24h and generated some clicks, there is only one strange error in the LogCat (Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform) and InMobi is printing some responses in LogCat.

Example response from InMobi:

```
InMobiAndroidSDK_3.6.2 : requestactivity=AdRequest&tp=c_gwhirl&u-rt=0&d-device-screen-density=1.5&d-device-screen-size=480X854&mk-siteid=a84ad8be300942ef8d356180085f8a41&u-id-map=uoJf3VOg5BXq327SMdvB5HwqkNA3jxHbj5FTAQhhpjIvzCnyMm%2BbQ3gGYv6%2BFukANGHv9uZdrfum%0AMcqlu8fqSw%3D%3D%0A&u-id-key=-991818964&u-key-ver=1&aid=bd3df942-9b44-49db-a8ed-798012f10bbb&mk-version=pr-SAND-DTGTC-20121219&mk-rel-version=3.6.2&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+2.3.4%3B+en-gb%3B+LT18i+Build%2F4.0.2.A.0.62%29+AppleWebKit%2F533.1+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F533.1&u-appBId=counterpicks.leagueoflegends&u-appDNM=LoL+Counter+picker&u-appVer=1.12&d-localization=en_gb&d-netType=wifi&d-orientation=1&mk-ad-slot=15

InMobiAndroidSDK_3.6.2 : Ad Response: <AdResponse><Ads></Ads></AdResponse>
```

So I guess that's a normal, working response.

No idea why mediation doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that waiting 24h wasn't enough. After about 48h everything started to work.